# Get selected item position of RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-intent, android-recyclerview, popupmenu

I am trying to get position of the clicked item in RecyclerView. In adapter class, I am trying to create intent and send clicked item's contents. Also I created popup menu for two option. It is in adapter class too. onBindViewHolder position is works for puting contents in the rows of RecyclerView. However I couldn't reach that position from outside of method.

This is adapter class.

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> implements PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener {

    public ArrayList<MovieModel.Results> resultList;
    public Context context;


    public RecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<MovieModel.Results> list, Context context) {
        this.resultList = list;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ImageView posterImage;
        ImageView addIcon;
        TextView movieName;
        TextView date;
        TextView overview;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            posterImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.movie_poster);
            addIcon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.addImage);
            movieName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.movieNameText);
            date = itemView.findViewById(R.id.dateText);
            overview = itemView.findViewById(R.id.overviewText);

        }
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.movie_list_2, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(itemView);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        if (position < getItemCount()) {
            String title = resultList.get(position).getTitle();
            String date = resultList.get(position).getRelease_date();
            String overview = resultList.get(position).getOverview();
            String posterPath = resultList.get(position).getPoster_path();

            holder.movieName.setText(title);
            holder.date.setText(date);
            holder.overview.setText(overview);

            if (posterPath == null) {
                holder.posterImage.setImageDrawable(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.no_poster));
            } else {
                Glide.with(context).load(FeedActivity.BASE_PHOTO_URL + posterPath).into(holder.posterImage);
            }


            int finalPosition = position;
            holder.addIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //Toast.makeText(context, "You clicked : " + finalPosition, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    showPopup(v);
                }
            });
        }
        position++;
    }


    private void showPopup(View v) {

        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(context,v);
        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
        MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, popup.getMenu());
        popup.show();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

        // Here I need to position of clicked item in Recyclerview, and I will get title, date etc.

        int pos;

        if(item.getItemId() == R.id.menuAdd){

            // Find here to get position of clicked movie.
            String title = resultList.get(pos).getTitle();
            String date = resultList.get(pos).getRelease_date();
            String overview = resultList.get(pos).getOverview();
            String posterpath = resultList.get(pos).getPoster_path();

            Intent intent1 = new Intent(context,ListActivity.class);
            intent1.putExtra("title",title);
            intent1.putExtra("date",date);
            intent1.putExtra("overview",overview);
            intent1.putExtra("posterpath",posterpath);
            context.startActivity(intent1);
            return true;

        }
        else if(item.getItemId() == R.id.menuShowDetails){

            int movieId = resultList.get(pos).getMovieId();

            Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, MovieDetails.class);
            intent1.putExtra("movie_id",movieId);
            context.startActivity(intent1);
            return true;

        }

        return false;
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return resultList.size();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the ViewHolder's `getAdapterPosition()` to retrieve the item's position within an interface method. Then store the clicked position in a member variable.

Additionally, there shouldn't be a need to call `position++` from within your `onBindViewHolder`.

```
// Create a member variable to store the clicked position
public int clickedPos = -1;

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    
    // ...
    
    holder.addIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // When you're inside the click listener interface,
            // you can access the position using the ViewHolder.
            // We'll store the position in the member variable in this case.
            clickedPos = holder.getAdapterPosition();
        }
    });
    
    // Remove the 'position++' call as the position should already be handled without explicitly updating it.
}

@Override
public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
    // You can use clickedPos here to perform whatever tasks you need.
    
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate it works now. Also I deleted incrementing position line. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome, @SuleymanOner. And please remember to mark the answer as accepted.